# Mounting heavy mirror that has a angled beveled frame

Tags: mounting, mirror, frame

I would like to hang a large heavy mirror (5' x 3) that has a bevelled frame as shown in the picture below.

The back of the mirror is made of 1/8" wood which I don't will be able to hold the weight well. The frame however is solid wood 1/2" thick which should nicely hold the weight of the mirror.

The frame edge is angled at about 35deg from the plane of the mirror.
How do I mount the such that the back is tight to the wall?

Any insight would be appreciated.

[image]

UPDATE:
As requested here is the picture of the side of the mirror and how it looks.
Is it feasible to put French cleats on this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have hung a lot of mirrors and started to write and answer...   But really I need to see a picture of this thing before I give you a good answer.   Wouldn't hurt to see where you want it too.

Comment: @DMoore, sorry for the late reply. I’ve updated my post with some pics. Hopefully this gives more perspective?

Comment: You will need to add/fasten (*glue and screw*) a strip of wood cut to a 35degree wedge to the back of the top rail of the frame.  This will give you a surface parallel to the wall for a french cleat. There are pre-made aluminum french cleats.  https://www.lowes.com/pd/Hillman-18-in-Hangman-Picture-Hanging-System/3058195

Comment: @AlaskaMan Just the Top rail would suffice for load distribution, or should I do the bottom as well?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a standard picture wire technique. Either one span for two wall anchors, or if that would show above the frame, use two shorter ones.

Purchase a frame hanging kit, which would include the screw-on eyelets, or just put screws into the frame and wire to those. You might have to experiment a bit to find out how much slack is needed in the wire.

[image]

[Photo and more info from Home Depot](https://www.homedepot.com/c/ah/how-to-hang-a-heavy-mirror/9ba683603be9fa5395fab9014dac338b)

If you find that the frame vibrates against the wall when doors are closed, etc., a few felt pads would help.

Comment: It will always tip towards the bottom.  Even with a standard framed mirror this only works if it is relatively small.   With the weird beveled top and bottom I think this would stand out too much.

Comment: I don't believe so. The picture wire would be necessarily off the wall somewhat due to the tilted frame, which would result in a retraction force toward the wall. The wires would have to be kept snug enough that they'd remain interior of the rear edge of the frame, of course.

Comment: @isherwood, the mirror will be hung over the bed and is quite massive (around 5’ in length). 
Would a wire frame be resilient enough to be safe?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "wire frame", but the rule of thumb is to use wire with a breaking strength four times the weight of the object. The rest is up to your craftsmanship.

Answer (score 0):

Another technique would be to use a French Cleat.
A 45 deg angle of wood or aluminum.
You could custom fit one in the beveled area and get it flat to the wall.
You could put one on the bottom too for stability.

[Example Article](https://www.homeconstructionimprovement.com/how-to-hang-a-large-picture-french-cleat/)

Comment: It is a good general idea but the cleat would have to be inside the frame.   You do not want it on the back of the mirror and the mirror is 1"+ out from the wall wobbling on this.

Comment: That's what I meant by fitting it to the beveled area, which is the frame.

Comment: I think both of the answers we have here can't be verified because there is no picture of the mirror.   Your answer is better if there is a way to secure the cleat.   I don't see how to do that unless the mirror comes out in the middle (highly doubt) or you glue it - which I would not trust long term.